# Unexpected behaviour when merging two IObservables

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have the following situation in my recent "Play With Rx"-project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var observable1 = Observable.Create<int>(
               (Func<IObserver<int>, IDisposable>)GenerateSequence);
        var observable2 = Observable.Create<int>(
               (Func<IObserver<int>, IDisposable>)GenerateSequence);
        var merged = observable1.Merge(observable2);

        observable1.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("1: " + i.ToString()));
        observable2.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("2: " + i.ToString()));
        merged.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Merged: " + i.ToString()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int count = 0;

    private static IDisposable GenerateSequence(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                observer.OnNext(count++);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }
}
```

Now, I expected to see something like

```
1: 0
2: 1
Merged: 0
Merged: 1
1: 2
2: 3
Merged: 2
Merged: 3
```

Instead I am seeing

```
1: 0
2: 1
Merged: 2
Merged: 3
1: 4
2: 5
Merged: 6
Merged: 7
```

If I replace the loop by

```
while (true)
{
    observer.OnNext(r.Next(0, 1000));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

for a either static or local instance r of Random, the merged sequence has other numbers in it that the two seperate sequences!

I do not see how `count++` or `r.Next(0, 1000)` can be executed multiple times from one call of `observer.OnNext(...)`. What about Merge do I not understand?

P.S.: I've tried to eliminate race conditions by locks or seperating the loop times of the two threads, but the result was unchanged, so I left these attempts out of the question.

**Edit:** It seems that `GenerateSequence` is called 4 times, so that 4 threads are spun up to increment `count`. While this explains what I see, I do not understand why it should be so.

Comment: Isn't it the all essence of capture variables, that it holds a reference to `count` until executing the function which only then evaluate the value of it ?

Comment: As far as I know, in C# integers are passed by value. Even if I change the code to `int temp = count++; observer.OnNext(temp);` the behaviour is unchanged.

Comment: Every variable in C# is passed by value, even reference type. Try doing `int temp = ++count; observer.OnNext(temp);`

Comment: This change does not change the behaviour I observe.

Comment: Then fix it accordingly, as long as you use a temporary variable to hold the current number, because the captured `count` variable is messing with you. Try `int temp = count++; observer.OnNext(temp);` if that serve you more accurately. [Edited]

Comment: @OrelEraki that's not the problem here. I tested with Interlocked.Increment and also your temp suggestion and both have the issue. The problem here is that you have 3 "live" observables which will each generate their sequence. What you need to understand about Merge is that you're meant to merge two or more cold observables that haven't been activated yet (i.e. have no subscribers) and then use that instead. If your observables are active (by means of having subscribers) and you merge them, all of them will run as far as I understand. In short, remove your two individual subscriptions...

Comment: And only subscribe to the merged one and it will work as you expect it to.

Comment: I know you're just testing, but looking at your code I see you're doing `return Disposable.Empty;`. That's a bad thing. There's almost always a way to return a real disposable. In your code's case I would use the built-in `Observable.Generate(...)` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When you subscribe to `observable1`, you subscribe to `Observable.Create(GenerateSequence)`, which calls `GenerateSequence` and starts a loop.
- When you subscribe to `observable2`, you subscribe to `Observable.Create(GenerateSequence)`, which calls `GenerateSequence` and starts a loop.
- When you subscribe to `merged`, you subscribe to `Observable.Merge(observable1, observable2)`, which subscribes to `observable1` and `observable2`. We saw in the first two points what happens when you do each of those.

The net result is four calls to `GenerateSequence`.

To get an effect pretty close to you're looking for, you need to look at `Publish()`:

```
var observable1 = Observable
    .Create<int>((Func<IObserver<int>, IDisposable>)GenerateSequence)
    .Publish();
var observable2 = Observable
    .Create<int>((Func<IObserver<int>, IDisposable>)GenerateSequence)
    .Publish();
var merged = observable1.Merge(observable2);

observable1.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("1: " + i.ToString()));
observable2.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("2: " + i.ToString()));
merged.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Merged: " + i.ToString()));

observable1.Connect();
observable2.Connect();
```

`observable1` and `observable2` are now of type `IConnectableObservable`, which means they hold off subscribing to their underlying `IObservable` (`Observable.Create` in your case) until they have `Connect` called.

Output

```
1: 0
Merged: 0
2: 1
Merged: 1
1: 2
Merged: 2
2: 3
Merged: 3
...
```